# How do I get posts orderby title with some addtional meta key values

Tags: php, wordpress

I was searching for this but didn't find the solution. I am getting posts orderby title but some posts need to come first so I added a custom field which `meta_key` is `display_postion` and the values for this fields are **numbers** i.e. 1,2,3. So how do I achieve this, below is my current code.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'         => 'products',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'paged'             => $paged
   ;
   $wp_query =  new WP_Query( $args );
   if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Is this an `$args` array for `WP_Query()`? Please specify or provide additional code context.

Comment: @esqew just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `meta_value_num` to an `orderby` array and referencing `'display_position'` in the `meta_key` field should do the trick:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        'title' => 'ASC'
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'display_position'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($wp_query->have_posts()):
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()):
        $wp_query->the_post();
```

See documentation for [Order and Orderby parameters for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: I am not getting posts now